# Local web server

Tags: macos, webserver

I'm running OS X Yosemite and I'm trying to setup Apache so I can access files over my WiFi for my Chromecast application (runs using NodeJS).

So I followed some tutorials online (http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/re-enable-apache-php-web-sharing-on-os-x-yosemite/) and I can access my websites at:

`http://localhost/~cameron`

I can also access something at:

`cameron.local/~cameron`

**One thing that's confusing me is where does just localhost and cameron.local point? I can't find the file I see anywhere! I tried `/Library/WebServer/Documents` but it's NOT the index.php file there... Any ideas where I can find it? Or find out? A spotlight search for the contents doesn't return anything!**

Anyway when trying to access the contents of an example site on say my iPhone, etc, I can't do it! Because of my use of `localhost` so it would try and find the localhost of the device rather than my Mac.

I thought I could just replace `localhost` with my ip address... but when I enter my ip address nothing happens... I just get an endless loading.

How do I solve this? Do you have to do anything special to get ip addresses working?

Shouldn't just be able to do:

`xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~cameron/examplewebsite`

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial you've followed? It will make it easier for others to understand what your setup is now? Also, which files did you modify/install/add?

Comment: Added the tutorial link.

Comment: cameron.local should let people access the sites folder in your home directory (~/Sites)

Comment: `http://cameron.local/` should be identical to `http://localhost/`. To access the content of a user-specific Sites folder, use `http://cameron.local/~cameron`. Does this reduce your confusion?

Comment: Be careful here: `cameron.local` should be the same as `localhost` when browsed to on your Mac called `cameron`. It will **not** be the same as `cameron.local/~cameron` or `localhost/~cameron` (which between the two of them should be the same).

Comment: Yeah but I don't know where cameron.local and localhost are pointing when I don't specify the username... In any case the ip address is what I'm really trying to get working.